# PCA applied to MFCC for feeding a GMM classifier (sklearn library)

Tags: python, classification, pca, mfcc

I'm facing a (probably simple) problem where I have to reduce the dimensionality of my features vector using PCA. The main point of all of this is to create a classifier that predicts a sentence composed by phonemes. I train my model with hours of sentences pronounced by people (the sentences are only 10), each sentence has a label composed by a set of phonemes (see below).

What I have done so far is the following:

```
import mdp
from sklearn import mixture
from features import mfcc

def extract_mfcc():
    X_train = []
    directory = test_audio_folder

    # Iterate through each .wav file and extract the mfcc
    for audio_file in glob.glob(directory):
        (rate, sig) = wav.read(audio_file)
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig, rate)

        X_train.append(mfcc_feat)
    return np.array(X_train)

def extract_labels():
    Y_train = []

    # here I have all the labels - each label is a sentence composed by a set of phonemes
    with open(labels_files) as f:
        for line in f:  # Ex: line = AH0 P IY1 S AH0 V K EY1 K
            Y_train.append(line)
        return np.array(Y_train)

def main():
   __X_train = extract_mfcc()
   Y_train = extract_labels()

   # Now, according to every paper I read, I need to reduce the dimensionality of my mfcc vector before to feed my gaussian mixture model
   
   X_test = []
   for feat in __X_train:
       pca = mdp.pca(feat)
       X_test.append(pca)

   n_classes = 10 # I'm trying to predict only 10 sentences (each sentence is composed by the phonemes described above)
   gmm_classifier = mixture.GMM(n_components=n_classes, covariance_type='full')
   gmm_classifier.fit(X_train)  # error here!reason: each "pca" that I appended before in X_train has a different shape (same number of columns though)
```

How can I reduce the dimensionality and, at the same time, have the same shape for each **PCA** that I extract ?

I also tried a new thing: calling the **gmm_classifier.fit(...)** within the for loop where I obtain the **PCA** vector (see code below). The function **fit()** works but I'm not sure whether I'm actually training the GMM correctly or not.

```
n_classes = 10
gmm_classifier = mixture.GMM(n_components=n_classes, covariance_type='full')

X_test = []
for feat in __X_train:
    pca = mdp.pca(feat)
    gmm_classifier.fit(pca) # in this way it works, but I'm not sure if it actually model is trained correctly
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Shouldn't you PCA your whole data first and then train your GMM classifier with the new reduced data?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your last comment/question:
    gmm_classifier.fit(pca) # in this way it works, but I'm not sure if it actually model is trained correctly
Whenever you call this, the classifier forgets the previous information and be only trained by the last data. Try appending the feats inside the loop and then fit.